# Remove product count from layered navigation magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, layered-navigation

I've been trying to remove the product count from the `manufacturer attribute` I'm using in the layered navigation. When using the setting `Show product count` and turn it off, it won't hide the product count from my attribute. Where do I need to change this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is option to disable the count from your Magento Admin interface:

**Store -> Configuration -> Catalog ->** find '**Layered Navigation**' then set **-> Display Product Count**

Answer (score 0):

Remove product count from all layered navigation filter option just disable **"Display Product Count"** option (set yes to no).

path: **admin -> Stores -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Layered Navigation -> Display Product Count**

Run below command.

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex